# NoSuchAlgorithmException using default SSL Java

Tags: java, ssl

I have recently been converting my messaging system to SSL Sockets, and it was all going well until I started running into a NoSuchAlgorithm Exception, I have found it is due to not finding my selfsigned.jks in my main method I set it, and it is definitely a file, so any thoughts on why this might be happening?

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "selfsigned.jks");
```

Comment: File name is unqualified, and maybe current directory is not what you think it is?

Comment: works now, cheers!